# Can I link two Macbooks to use DVD authoring software on one and the Superdrive to burn it on the other?

Tags: macbook-pro, optical-drive, dvd-burning

My Macbook Pro 2017 (running Mojave) has no DVD drive, of course; but my Macbook early 2009 Superdrive (running El Capitan) can burn them, as well as my iMac 2011 (running High Sierra). Can I connect the Macbook Pro to one of these two computers, use the Roxio Titanium software on my Macbook Pro, but burn the DVD on one of the Superdrives?

I'm looking at purchasing Roxio Toast Titanium 19, but open to suggestions for other software. I won't be doing a large amount of DVD authoring, just hobby stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not install Toast on both, then you can send a .toast image from one to the other & burn from the old machine. DVDs tend to be quite fussy about getting data in time, so trying to do this 'live' over a network could result in buffer underrun & a wasted disc.

Comment: Tonia: It would be helpful if you could add the following to your question. Which versions of OS X and macOS do you intend to use on both the 2009 and 2017 Macs? Which version of Roxio Titanium do you currently have or intend to purchase?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need DVDs? All my discs became rubbish after a couple decades, so it is not safe to store data. The space is really small (740MB), the video quality is awful and clumsy, with pixel aspect ratio issues... I liked building menus, it is the only thing I miss, but there are other tools nowadays, even a simple HTML interface will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either one can [mount disks on the other](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-file-sharing-on-mac-mh17131/mac), but it might be more efficient to save a DVD image onto an external disk, then move the disk to the other machine.

Comment: You are giving a link where one may view the contents of the DVD through smb. I do not think this is the same as [accessing as a remote disc](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-dvds-and-cds-on-mac-mh19569/mac). On a 2018 Mac mini running Mojave, I can open a DVD as a remote disc and using smb. Get Info on both is shown [here](https://imgur.com/a/Dr2hJ38). The DVD is inserted in the internal optical drive of a 2011 iMac running High Sierra.

Comment: No, file sharing allows a disk or directory of any type on one Mac to be mounted on another.  But it’s speed-limited to the data path between them.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2011 iMac running High Sierra with a builtin SuperDrive. I can access this drive as a [Remote Disc](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-dvds-and-cds-on-mac-mh19569/mac) from a 2018 Mac mini running Mojave. However, I can not use the Remote Disc to burn DVDs from the 2018 Mac mini using the software included with Mojave. I do not see how installing Roxio Toast Titanium would change this. However, I could be wrong.

You could try using Roxio Toast Titanium on the 2017 Macbook Pro, then using the 2009 Macbook to burn, but this might require owning a Roxio Toast Titanium license for each machine. The newest version of Roxio Toast Titanium that will run on a 2009 MacBook is version 18. If the 2017 Macbook Pro is running Big Sur, you may need to install the current version of Roxio Toast Titanium, which is version 19. I do not know if Disc Images saved using version 19 can be accessed and burned using version 18.

Another option would be to purchase an external [Apple USB SuperDrive](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD564LL/A/apple-usb-superdrive) and the Apple [USB-C to USB Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter). This will allow you to do everything from the 2017 Macbook Pro. If purchased from Apple, the cost would be 98 USD, however, cheaper optical drives may be found which may not need an adaptor.